# iterate over multiple nested results using subprocess

Tags: python, loops

Ok.  I've got two shell commands that return string results, which I then need to process further. The first command produces a result (hostnames), and then the next command takes the result of the first, to expand another, more extensive list of hostnames.  This is in order to generate a list of hosts to run another shell command on.

I don't need a complete example, just some steering in the right direction.

```
import subprocess

def getMasterList():
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(['get_master_list'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p2 = subprocess.Popen(['grep', '-v', '\['], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    master_list = p2.communicate()[0]
    return master_list.split()

def getHostsFromList(master):
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(['get_hosts_from_master', master], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p2 = subprocess.Popen(['grep', '-v', '\['], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print p2.communicate()[0]

def doStuff(host):
    p = subprocess.Popen('run_shell_command', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    print p.stdout.read()

for master in getMasterList():
    getHostsFromList(master)
    # How do I iterate further to run doStuff() over the hosts from getHostsFromList(master)?
```

Comment: Can you replace the last line of `getHostsFromList()` to return `p2.communicate()[0].split()` and use a for loop, just like you did before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe i'm missing something, but isn't it just:

```
def getHostsFromList(master):
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(['get_hosts_from_master', master], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p2 = subprocess.Popen(['grep', '-v', '\['], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    return p2.communicate()[0]

for master in getMasterList():
    for host in getHostsFromList(master):
        doStuff(host)
```